# How PHP uploading Documents Works with posting document on the same page of Website?

Tags: php, html, post, upload

I have been playing with various php upload examples to get a feel of how it works.

Before my database is in place, I want to understand why when I click my "post comment" button on my form that it goes to another page showing my whole php code. (is this due to database not made yet?)

I also think that I am not understanding the line of code: "$upload_path ="

I put the directory path of the folder containing my text document. From what I have been reading it said it has to be a directory and usually only has examples of just "\files\" or "\uploads\" which doesn't make sense to me.

Also what does:

```
$filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
```

line of code mean or does?

**I want my upload to post to my website. In other words, click upload button and the document displays below the form on the same page.**

I have a html form inside a html document and then I have a separate php document.

HTML:

```
<form id="comments" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: <input type="text" name="comment">
<br>

Text Document: <input type="file" name="documentfile" />
<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment" class="button">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$allowed_filetypes = array('.text'); // types of files to use 
$max_size = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
$upload_path = '\\ps....\ps.....\w...\Data\Aly...\HTML\TechSite - Copy\TechSite - Copy\files'; 

$filename = $_FILES['documentfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file and extension.

$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get file extension

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not tell user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Check filesize, if too large tell user.
if(filesize($_FILES['documentfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// Check if we can upload to  path, if not tell user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

// Upload the file to your specified path.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documentfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . 

$filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
else
echo 'There was an error during the file upload. Please try again.';

?>
```

Once again: I played with examples I found for the php file because I am learning as I go with it. Please let me know if there is something in the php file that doesn't make sense and explain if possible. I'm wanting to understand if my php will be ok once my database is in place. I'd appreciate it!

Comment: For some reason, I feel that my database needs to be in place before I can test my php correct?

Comment: No - PHP can run without a database. If you're "showing my whole php code" then your server is not running PHP and needs to be configure correctly to run it.

Comment: Ohhh ok that makes sense. I will read into doing that. :)